# Odoo nginx sub url as location /

Tags: nginx, odoo

I have this problem, Odoo in proxy pass that needs to redirect location / to odoo_ip:8069/my-location. The main problem here is the petitions are not loading and returns 404.

```
#odoo server
upstream odoo {
  server 127.0.0.1:8069;
}
upstream odoochat {
  server 127.0.0.1:8072;
}

# http -> https
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name MY_URL;
  rewrite ^(.*) https://$host$1 permanent;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name MY_URL;
  proxy_read_timeout 720s;
  proxy_connect_timeout 720s;
  proxy_send_timeout 720s;
  # Error 500 handling
  proxy_intercept_errors on;

  # Add Headers for odoo proxy mode
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

  # Add Headers
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always;
  add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
  add_header X-Xss-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
  add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
  add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src https: data: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; frame-ancestors 'self'" always;
  add_header Referrer-Policy "same-origin" always;
  add_header Set-Cookie "Path=/; HttpOnly; Secure";

  # SSL parameters
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/nginx/server.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/nginx/server.key;
  ssl_session_timeout 30m;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;

  # log
  access_log /var/log/nginx/odoo.access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/odoo.error.log;

  # Redirect longpoll requests to odoo longpolling port
  location /longpolling {
    proxy_pass http://odoochat;
  }

  # Redirect requests to odoo backend server
  location / {
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://odoo/my-url; # This generate 404 in assets and others.
    proxy_cookie_path / "/; SameSite=None; HTTPOnly; Secure";
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =500;
  }

  # common gzip
  gzip_types text/css text/scss text/plain text/xml application/xml application/json application/javascript;
  gzip on;

  # 50.x errors
  error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
  location = /50x.html {
      ssi on;
      root /usr/share/nginx/html/;
      index 50x.html
      internal;
  }
}
```

And this is the behavior from nginx

```sh
https://my-url/ -> http://odoo_ip:8069/my-url
# This is correct
https://my-url/web/assets -> http://odoo_ip:8069/my-url/assets
# Return 404 because my-location generates the error.
```

So, I know this can be tricky, but there is a simple way to do that? Because almost every url should need a proxy_pass configuration.